# How to convert a string() to a string

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

Hi I am making a slot machine game in visual basic (as a console application) and I cant seem to put the value that is randomly picked from the array into a string data type. It tells me that

> The value of string() can not be converted to string

This is my code:

```
slot1 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
slot2 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
slot3 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}

Console.WriteLine(slot1(rand.Next(0, slot1.Length)))
slotmachine1 = slot1

If slotmachine1 = "Apple" Then
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Cherry" Then
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Banana" Then
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
End If
```

Otherwise the program works fine so does anyone know a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: I found that `slotmachine1` is an array of strings, hence use indexing or iterate it with `For Each` loop like `For Each str In slotmachine1`.

Comment: So what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You are trying to assing an array (doesn't matter if it is an array of strings) to a single string. What should do the compiler for you? Choose a single string from that array? Concatenate all your strings inside the array to a single string? As you can see this operation is indefinable in a generic way. It is up to you to choose the string inside the array and assign THAT string to your destination variable

Comment: You need to store the randomly generated number into a variable, then use that as an index for your arrays: `slotmachine1 = slot1(randomNum)` (or: `If slot1(randomNum) = "Apple" Then`)

Comment: [This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tp6wmD) may help you figure out how to compare with specified string. I used `slot1` with randomized indexing in a variable to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign an array to a string. Save your random number to a variable and use that to read the value from the array.

```
Dim slotmachine1 as String
dim RandomNumber as integer

slot1 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
slot2 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
slot3 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}

RandomNumber = rand.Next(0, slot1.Length)

Console.WriteLine(slot1(RandomNumber))
slotmachine1 = slot1(RandomNumber)

If slotmachine1 = "Apple" Then
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Cherry" Then
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Banana" Then
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
End If
```

Comment: The rand.Next method is inclusive of the first parameter and exclusive of the second parameter so the OP's `rand.Next(0, slot1.Length)` is correct.

Comment: Saving the random number is not necessary. `slotmachine1 = slot1(rand.Next(0, slot1.Length)`

Comment: @Mary It is if you want to use the `Console.Writeline` in between. If not then you can indeed use the code you wrote. Don't forget to put `-1` after `slot1.Length` because it is a zero based index.

Comment: No Martin, on two counts. #1 You already have the string to display in `Console.WriteLine(slotmachine1)` No index necessary. #2 either you didn't read or did believe my first comment. -1 will not include the last index.

Comment: @Mary I'm sorry, you are totally right. I actually responded to your second comment without reading the first one. The manual clearly says the second parameter for rand.next is exclusive. I updated the answer to correct this.